# SQL Query grouping by a same ID

Tags: sql

Supppose I have a table called 'AnimalClass' that looks like this:

| AnimalId | Gender | SocialID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | male | X001 |
| 1 | female | X2F8 |
| 1 | none | XGW7 |
| 2 | male | A902 |
| 2 | female | A2F5 |
| 2 | none | AGW6 |
| 3 | male | T0R3 |
| 3 | female | T2F0 |
| 3 | none | TGW1 |

I am looking for a query that would return only 'male' and 'female' genders that share a same Animalid category where the Socialid matches 'X2F8' OR 'A2F5'

Basically the result should be only male and female genders that share a matching Animalid and the Socialid of the female matches 'X2F8' OR 'A2F5':

| AnimalId | Gender | SocialID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | male | X001 |
| 1 | female | X2F8 |
| 2 | male | A902 |
| 2 | female | A2F5 |

I've made a few attempts but I just can wrap my head around it:

```
SELECT * FROM AnimalClass 
   WHERE (Gender = 'male' OR Gender = 'female')
   AND (SocialID = 'X2F8' OR SocialID = 'A2F5')
```

This query doesn't eventually give me results for both male and female but only for female.

Comment: Since SQL includes data definition, a [mcve] for an [SQL question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/90527) should include [DDL](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statements for sample tables (rather than an ad hoc table specification) and [DML](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statements for sample data (rather than a dump or ad hoc format). Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.

Comment: Please tag this question with the RDBMS you're using or, if it should work for any RDBMS, mention so in the question.

Comment: Don't use [`SELECT *`](/q/321299/90527) unless you're writing a DB administration program; select only the columns you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with EXISTS

```
SELECT a1.* 
FROM AnimalClass a1
WHERE (Gender = 'male' OR Gender = 'female')
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM AnimalClass a2
    WHERE (a2.SocialID = 'X2F8' OR a2.SocialID = 'A2F5')
       AND a2.AnimalId = a1.AnimalId
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Using joins, the requirements translate fairly directly into SQL.

> the result should be only male and female genders

This translates to a `Gender IN ('male', 'female')` in the `WHERE` clause on the result rows.

> that share a same Animalid category

This is where the join comes in, as you're comparing rows with each other. This also identifies the join column: `AnimalId`

> the Socialid of the female matches 'X2F8' OR 'A2F5'

This translates to a `Gender = 'female' AND SocialID IN ('X2F8', 'A2F5')` in the `WHERE` clause on the comparison rows (i.e. not the result rows).

Since the conditions should all hold, they're combined with `AND`.

Put that all together, and you get:

```
SELECT results.AnimalId, results.Gender, results.SocialID
  FROM AnimalClass AS results
    JOIN AnimalClass AS filter ON results.AnimalId = filter.AnimalId
  WHERE results.Gender IN ('male', 'female')
    AND filter.Gender = 'female'
    AND filter.SocialID IN ('X2F8', 'A2F5')
;
```